# Patent abandonment and revival

Tags: abandoned-patent, patent-revival

I would like to reapply for my own abandoned patent modification that I had to reluctantly abandon because I couldn't afford the periodic fees. If indeed there are exceptional circumstances such as temporary unafforability, will the new patent be good for 20 years or for the years that were remaining before I abandoned it?

Comment: What do you mean by “patent modification”?

Comment: If there is a way to revive it the end of its term will not be any different from the original end date. We need more and clearer info to provide a good answer.